# mysql gem vs mysql2 gem and 'each_hash' method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Previously I have used `mysql` RubyGem in my app. Now I have switched to `mysql2` RubyGem and I'm having problems with `Result` class.

Code example:

```
db_values = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

db_values.each_hash do |db_value|
  ret_val << MyValue.do_smth_with_data(db_value)
end
```

Previously (in mysql RubyGem) there was `each_hash` method for looping through the data. In mysql2 RubyGem there is just a 3 possible methods (count, each, fields) for Result class and one of them is `each` method, but that is not what I need to loop fetched data.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the mysql2 gem includes the `Enumerable` module, so you just use `each` instead of `each_hash`.

Answer (score 1):

The Connection's select_all method is also useful here.  It "returns an array of record hashes with the column names as keys and column values as values."